# node.js csv how to handle bad data

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, error-handling, stream

I have an application parsing csv file. I used [csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) module and it basically works fine. However, once there is a bad row in the csv file, the whole process fails.

Is there anyway to skip bad rows and resume streaming after catching an error?

This is a simple example

```
var csv = require('csv');
var stream = require('stream');

var parser = csv.parse({ delimiter: "," });

parser.on("data", (chunk) => {
    console.log("one chunk");
    chunk.forEach((datum) => {
        console.log("data: ", datum);
    });
});

parser.on("error", (err) => {
    // Skip the error and resume stream here
    console.log("one error: ", err.message);
});

var test = "00,01,02,03\n10,11,12,23\n21,22,\n30,31,32,33";

var rs = new stream.Readable();

rs._read = () => {};
rs.push(test);

rs.pipe(parser);
```

Here the third row has only three columns while other rows have four. I want to catch the error and write out all other rows. Is there any good strategy to do this? Using some function or option in csv module will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two things here.
The first one is that you can use the `relax_column_count: true` in `csv.parse` options, and it should be working.

But if you test it you will see that the last line is missing. In fact in the way you pass your stream even with a proper csv string it would fail! Although if you pass a proper csv file it will work, so I suspect that there is something wrong with the stream also.

So to sum up this is the code.

```js
var csv = require('csv');

var parser = csv.parse({ relax_column_count:true, delimiter: "," });

parser.on("data", (chunk) => {
    console.log("one chunk");
    chunk.forEach((datum) => {
        console.log("data: ", datum);
    });
});

parser.on("error", (err) => {
    // Skip the error and resume stream here
    console.log("one error: ", err.message);        
})
parser.on('close',function(){
  console.log(parser)
})

require('fs').createReadStream('test.csv').pipe(parser);
```

And in `test.csv`

```
00,01,02,03
10,11,12,23
21,22,23,24
30,31,
34,35,36,37
```

**As requested here is the code working with stream**

```js
var csv = require('csv');
var stream = require('stream');

var parser = csv.parse({ relax_column_count:true, delimiter: "," });

parser.on("data", (chunk) => {
    console.log("one chunk");
    chunk.forEach((datum) => {
        console.log("data: ", datum);
    });
});

parser.on("error", (err) => {
    // Skip the error and resume stream here
    console.log("one error: ", err.message);        
})
parser.on('close',function(){
  console.log(parser)
})

var test = "00,01,02,03\n10,11,12,23\n21,22,\n30,31,32,33"

const myReadable = new stream.Readable({
  read(size) {
    this.push(test)
    test = null
  }
});
myReadable.pipe(parser);
```

I believe the problem with your stream was that you didn't push `null` in the end and it didn't end it in a good manner.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried this code. As you said, it printed the bad row but not the last good row. This is not what I expected. It doesn't catch the error. You mentioned there are two ways to do it at the beginning of the answer. What's the other way to do it?

Comment: I see what you mean by "two things". The real problem is that using relax_column_count option only stop showing error but not actually solves the issue. What I want is catch the error and parse or good data.